# Nearest possible solution to replace arrays with something that could check bounds c++

Tags: c++

I have ~15'000 lines C/C++ program and somewhere in it - simple array is used out of boundaries(its my guess), cause of 'undefined behaviour' happens(well, no, my cdrom isn't opening randomly) but heap memory is modified from somewhere in code ! some defined integers memory just goes into inaccesible, random exceptions of memory where it shouldnt happen, and if i remove or change anything exceptions occurs elsewhere, strange and scarry... 
So, i need to replace 100 arrays with anything what would check boundaries properly. And that anything would require minimal modifications.

Can i maybe create a class which mimics arrays behaviour but checks for boundaries, so i could change all arrays easly ? or which solution in this case would you offer ? I am kinda new in c++, any examples is gold for me.

I am using Windows 7, 
by  saying simple array i mean:

```
int data[400];
data[20] = 4; // its fine
data[-13] = 9; // opens cdrom, or formats hard drive, or works till your windows gets updated
```

Comment: can you put out some of your code so that we can see?

Comment: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: This can indeed be pretty tricky to debug. I suggest using valgrind or an equivalent tool that could give you more information about the invalid memory access.

Comment: Depending on the OS you're running on, use a proper memory debugger like Valgrind or Purify.

Comment: If you know which part of the heap is getting overwritten, look into [data breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for your debugger of choice.

Comment: What do you think about  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/130768/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpected modification of heap memory **could** be due to array boundary violations.

It **could also** be due to dereferencing dangling pointers.  In my experience, that's even more likely.

Across 15000 lines of code, the fastest way you could solve this mystery would be to invest the time to figure out how to use a tool like **[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)**.

Since you say you're *kinda new in C++*, you should note that the [standard library's template containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (like the bounds-check-able [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) go far to prevent both the issues I mention.

Comment: what i did: took std:array, modified it to check bounds by default via [] operator and modified all arrays to initialize my new array class. after checking everything i will disable default bounds checking everywhere or only where cpu optimization matters. found 2 arrays which goes out of bounds, but main failure was cause of usage of pointer to not properly initialized data.

Answer (score 1):

a simple, safe c++ array that checks bounds... have you heard of std::array?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing you could try is to link with debugging malloc library. No code changes, and it will likely to catch overruns in heap allocated arrays. If no catches then likely it is something bad on stack

On linux most used is electric fence, helped me a lot

There are ports of this library to Windows,

http://sourceforge.net/projects/duma/

https://code.google.com/p/electric-fence-win32/